# What is a word that means someone who hates their own race?

Tags: single-word-requests, racism

I'm seeking a word that means you hate your race for whatever reason, but you don't hate yourself for being a part of it, because it wasn't up to you to choose to be so.

Comment: Are you thinking of that lady who lied about being African-American? What's her name... [Rachel Dolezal](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/rachel-dolezal-storms-out-of-interview-after-being-asked-about-her-race-10315668.html)?

Comment: @Casey Affleck "Self-hating X," where X stands for whatever inherited or familial trait you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Rachel Dolezal doesn't seem to hate her "whiteness" as much as she identifies herself as black.

Comment: @Bravo yes, I agree. I was thinking that the OP is looking for an antonym of "ethnocentrism" but the details specifying "but you don't hate yourself for being a part of it" throws it off a bit. Hypocrisy?

Comment: 'race traitor'    ______________

Comment: david chapelle did a bit on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQtysS7fB4k - the blind racist. profound in many ways.

Comment: Depending on what context you are using "hate," **Uncle Tom** might capture some of the meaning. (Wikipedia: "...any person perceived to be complicit in the oppression of their own group.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very real thing, so deserves a good answer.

**self-loathing** suits.

The Wikipedia article uses **self-hating** in its article on [self-hating jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hating_Jew)

It should be noted the the term *self-hating jew* is considered pejorative, presumably because there are political or ideological implications of whether the persons loathing is genuine or reasonable.

Example usage:

> [Arthur Trebitchsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Trebitsch) was a self-hating jew who produced anti-semetic propaganda for the Nazis.
>
> Is Rachel Dolezal really a self-loathing white person, or is someone's ethnic identity fluid?

Ultimately the term should be used carefully, because it comes with some kind of judgement as to the person's motivations.

Answer (score 1):

A contextual rendering of **misanthropic** or its variant might fit.

> Misanthropic:
>
> OED: "Having or showing a dislike of other people; unsociable"
>
> MWD: "of, relating to, or characteristic of a misanthrope:  marked by a   hatred or contempt for humankind

As you can see this term is generally directed towards humanity or people as a whole, however the etymology suggests it could lend itself to other renderings. Misanthropic comes from the Greek morpheme **μισεω** (miseo) meaning hate and **ανθροπος** (anthropos), meaning people, person, or man. You could see how the hatred of one's own people might fit this word.

Answer (score 1):

A person who holds a belief that any particular race is inferior is a ***racist***, irrespective of whether they themselves are a member of said race.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to invoke a literary allusion, you could call such a person a **Gulliver**, referring to the revulsion that Lemuel Gulliver feels for his own kind (Yahoos) in the "A Voyage to the Country of the Houyhnhnms" section of [*Gulliver's Travels into Several Remote Nations of the World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=emISbmWjamwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Gulliver%27s+Travels%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIwK6NhP_YxgIVEEyICh0WfA6Z#v=onepage&q=%22Yahoos%22&f=false):

> I had hitherto concealed the secret of my dress, in order to distinguish myself, as much as possible, from that cursed race of Yahoos; but now I found it in vain to do so any longer.
>
> ...
>
> I expressed my uneasiness at his [Gulliver's Houyhnhnm master's] giving me so often the Appellation of Yahoo, an odious animal, for which I had so utter a hatred and contempt: I begged he would forebear applying that word to me, and make the same order in his family and among his friends whom he suffered to see me.
>
> ...
>
> When I thought of my family, my friends, my countrymen, or the human race in general, I considered them, as they really were, Yahoos is shape and disposition, perhaps a little more civilized, and qualified with the gift of speech; but making no other use of reason, than to improve and multiply those vices whereof their brethren in this country [Houyhnhnmland] had only the share that nature allotted them.

Later, in a retrospective note ("written in the year 1727") from Gulliver to his cousin after the initial publication of his *Travels*, Gulliver describes his feelings about typical Yahoos as follows:

> If the censure of the Yahoos could any way affect me, I should have great reason to complain, that some of them are so bold as to think my book of travels a mere fiction out of mine own brain, and have gone so far as to drop hints, that the Houyhnhnms and Yahoos have no more existence than the inhabitants of Utopia.
>
> ...
>
> Do these miserable animals [English Yahoos] presume to think, that I am so degenerated as to defend my veracity? Yahoo as I am, it is well known through all Houyhnhnmland, that, by the instructions and example of my illustrious master [a horse], I was able in the compass of two years (although I confess with the utmost difficulty) to remove that infernal habit of lying, shuffling, deceiving, and equivocating, so deeply rooted in the very souls of all my species; especially the Europeans.

Gulliver doesn't have a particularly high opinion of himself (he especially dislikes seeing reflections of himself in a mirror, window, or pool  of water), but his chief disgust is reserved for the race—the human race—of which he is a member.